# How to handle oversized operation while originating contract?

Tags: smartpy, error, origination

I was trying to originate a smart contract from legacy smartpy CLI.

I got this error:

```
[INFO] - Using RPC https://ghostnet.ecadinfra.com...
{
    "message": "Http error response: (500) [{\"kind\":\"temporary\",\"id\":\"failure\",\"msg\":\"Invalid operation oohqYgAvVmHJP4No2qPJyUUddmMzEaZkQ7c1VRYa2smEshnp6PQ: \\nError:\\n  Oversized operation (size: 36684, max: 32768)\\n.\"}]\n",
    "status": 500,
    "statusText": "Internal Server Error",
    "body": "[{\"kind\":\"temporary\",\"id\":\"failure\",\"msg\":\"Invalid operation oohqYgAvVmHJP4No2qPJyUUddmMzEaZkQ7c1VRYa2smEshnp6PQ: \\nError:\\n  Oversized operation (size: 36684, max: 32768)\\n.\"}]\n",
    "url": "https://ghostnet.ecadinfra.com/injection/operation",
    "name": "HttpResponse"
}
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If the operation is packed (eg. it's alongside a public key revelation), try to inject the revelation is a separate operation.

If you only injected the origination operation, the solution might be more tricky. Here are some hints:

- Try compiling with different SmartPy options if available to aggressively simplify the (size of the) generated code;
- If some parts of the SmartPy code could be simplified (eg. is dead code) or refactored, it should be done to reduce the size of the originated Michelson code;
- Register some portions of the code as global constants and use those constants in the code
- Register some portions of the code in a bigmap, and provide them later once the origination operation is included in the blockchain.